# Nodejs, Optimal parameters for sequelize connection pool?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, performance-testing

I found a lot of answers about config connection pool in java ex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8754088/1887799), event tool for profiling pool [flexy-pool](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool).

In our nodejs app, we started to have `SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError` errors, with default sequelize connection pool config.
We ran some performance tests using [locust](https://locust.io/) with different configurations:

[image: Stress test result]

I want to know what configuration you use, how you chose them.

Thanks!